# What defines jqXHR as "failed"

Tags: ajax, spring-security

I have a ajax request to a spring security backend. What happens for some reason is that `.then` doesn't occur ever. What I found out is that `.fail` occurs on every request, even though the request goes through, the login on the backend works and it returns a response with status code 200. So what defines a  jqXHR as failed and what do I need to add in the response so it works as it should?

Here is my ajax request:

```
  // Creates request object
function makeRequest(method, module, endpoint) {
    return req = {
        method,
        url: serverBaseUrl + module + '/' + endpoint
    };
}

// Function to return POST promise
function post (module, endpoint, data) {
    let req = makeRequest('POST', module, endpoint);
    req.data = data;
    return $.ajax(req);
}
```

And here is the response I get from my spring security setup:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 28 Mar 2018 01:02:20 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=8D6265E912D5DFCF418238F18586AFE1; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Comment: No hints in your browser console / debugger?

Comment: None that I can find. Do you have any suggestions what to look for?

Comment: I can only suggest adding a fail handler: `.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { debugger; });` and inspecting all of the parameters in the debugger when it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all my problem was in my `$.ajax` request. I had a `dataType` parameter added as `application/json`. That seems to be not valid. Found it out when i printed the error from the request when it failed. Got the answer from here:
[jquery ajax call return JSON parsing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456240/jquery-ajax-call-return-json-parsing-error?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)