# devops REST API: can not update work item status using PATCH method

Tags: javascript, ajax, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, http-patch

I am using DevOps restapi to get some information. 
The POST method is working fine for me. 
I want to update the status of my work item. For that I need to use the PATCH method. Which is not working, and not giving any kind of error.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

```
function postApiData(ApiUrl, responseBody) {
    var res = '';
    try {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            url: ApiUrl,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(responseBody),
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("" + ":" + _token));
            },
        }).done(function (data) {
            res = data;
        }).fail(function (e) {

        });
    } catch (error) {
        var x = error;
        throw x;
    }
    return res;
};
```

For Patch method, I am modifying a few things. but it is not giving any error not updating my work item. I have also checked my token access. I have full access.

```
type: 'PATCH',
contentType: 'application/json-patch+json',
```

Comment: I Guess they mixed up a lot regarding the method in the Azure DevOps documentation. Here you also see a [create call with a PUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/folders/create?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1) and an [Update call with a POST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/folders/update?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1).

I think you can do the following in general: Create = POST and Update = PUT

Comment: I have tried same thing with the post method but it is not updating.

Comment: Can you post the body you're sending in your PATCH?

Comment: @JigarParekh, you can use Fiddler to capture the error. It can show you why it didn't update work item successfully. Also, with the help of Fiddler, I wrote a simple sample which is work succeed now. You can try with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a simple sample on my side with `PATCH` in Ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#SelectWIT").on("click", function () {
        var json= [{
                "op": "add",
                "path": "/fields/System.State",
                "value": "Closed"
              }];
        $.ajax({
            type: 'PATCH',
            url: 'https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/_apis/wit/workitems/{WIT id}?api-version=5.1',
            contentType: 'application/json-patch+json',
            data: JSON.stringify(json),
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'application/json-patch+json',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("" + ":" + "{PAT token}"));
            },
        }).error(function (e) {
            var s = "error error error";
        });
    })
});
</script>
```

**Note:** Not only `contentType` need to set as `application/json-patch+json`, but also same in `dataType`.

---

I use Fiddler to catch this operation:

[image]

You can see the work item status updated successfully.

**UPDATE:**

[image]

Comment: This is working for me. But after updating status it is giving an error  in ajax "No conversion from text to application/json-patch+json"

Comment: @JigarParekh This should as expected. It represent did not get anything from server. Do you use the fiddler to capture this post? If yes, you would see that there’s nothing in the response body. Because server just get the post request and execute it, but nothing reply to client.

Comment: @JigarParekh, See my updated pic in the answer. You can see when you call the api with ajax, there's no response message replied from server(**But the operation is succeed**). As I checked from google, this seems the **default issue** of JQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456240/jquery-ajax-call-return-json-parsing-error. Not relevant with Azure Devops.