# How to get all user in organization by devops extenstions

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

i have an extension that install on azure devops. how can i get all user in my organization without register a client app with Azure DevOps => get token then call rest api ?
Because i want other people can install my extension, and they doesn't want to do any step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this api to get users in All Users page:

```
https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/_apis/UserEntitlements?%24filter=&%24orderBy=name%20Ascending
```

[image]

Comment: so, i will call a rest api after get the authenticate token right? at the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/auth?view=azure-devops

Comment: Azure Devops service provides VSS.require... to [call a rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/call-rest-api?view=azure-devops), however the rest api you need is not documented. So we can't use normal way to do that, you can try calling the rest api in [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59195324/10910450).